# Which software to use to show a bunch of photos and movie files one after another, as a slideshow?

Tags: software-recommendation, slideshow

My mother in law has sadly passed away. We have arranged a folder with a bunch of photos and short movies of her, that we'd like to show in a rolling slideshow at the funeral service. Ideally, it would step through all files chronolocially, showing each photo for 5 - 10 seconds, and display each movie in full with sound. When done, start over.

Any suggestions for which software I should use for this, on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Bash shellscript

I would create a bash shellscript, that uses graphical tools, that you can install and use from the shellscript with options, that make things run without manual interaction.

Make sure that you have the repositories universe and multiverse (I think they are there by default in an installed Ubuntu system, but you must add them in a persistent live system),

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt update
```

Install the restricted extras in order to manage several multimedia formats.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

### `feh` and `mplayer`

Install `feh` for pictures and `mplayer` for video clips

```
sudo apt install feh mplayer
```

### Edit the shellscript

If you have a fair number of pictures and video clips (in a dedicated directory),

- you can edit the shellscript to call `feh` (for pictures) and `mplayer` (for video clips) with each of the files as parameters

  you can `cd` to that directory and run the shellscript locally.

If you have a huge number of pictures and video clips (in a dedicated directory),

- you may prefer to prefix the file names with a number to select them in the order you want to play them.
- you can edit the the shellscript to call `feh` (for pictures) and `mplayer` (for video clips) with wild cards in the parameters.

### Example

I tested the following shellscript, and it works for me (both in a persistent live Ubuntu system and an installed Lubuntu system.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
 mplayer -fs 00007_360-50p.mp4 00007_720-50p.mp4
 feh -F -V -Z -D 5 --cycle-once uncropped-picture.png  cropped-picture.png
 mplayer -fs majaa.mp4
 read -n1 -t 5 -s -p "Press q to quit" ans
 echo ""
 if [ "$ans" == "q" ]
 then
  exit
 fi
done
```

You can press <kbd>q</kbd> to stop `feh`, `mplayer` and also the whole shellscript (when at the end, the command line with `read`).

Comment: That's a very thorough and well-written answer, thank you very much!

Comment: @Enfors, You are welcome. I hope it will work well for you.